# Firebase : Retrieve childByAutoID from Realtime Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently learning the ropes of Firebase and iOS so please bear with me. I'm currently posting to my table called `Posts` as shown here:

```
 let postInfo = ["Description": txtPostDescription.text!, "ImageUrl": imgUrl, "Likes": 0]

 var t = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postInfo)

 print(t)
```

I'm trying to retrieve the `primary key` that gets created when I insert the new record, however I'm unable to retrieve it.  I've tried `childByAutoId()` (*but that was a random guess due to browsing the web and not being able to find a solid solution*). Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
let postInfo = ["Description": txtPostDescription.text!, "ImageUrl": imgUrl, "Likes": 0]

var reference  = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").childByAutoId()

reference.setValue(postInfo)
let childautoID = reference.key 
print(childautoID)
```

**Note** :- Althogh `childByAutoId()` is a great functionality from `Firebase`.But prefer `timestamps` to store the data into when you want to create a node with a unique key.The reason why i prefer timestamps is because they can also be helpful in sorting of data...But thats just me..

Alternative :-

```
let timeStamp = Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()*1000) //Will give you a unique id every second or even millisecond if you want.. 
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").child(timeStamp).setValue(postInfo)
```

Comment: Working, Thanks @Dravidian

Comment: Thanks @Dravidian

Comment: Note that childByAutoId() *does* return a time-sortable ID: "The unique key generated by childByAutoId: is prefixed with a client-generated timestamp so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted." https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference