# iOS Firebase Stripe Integration w/ Cloud Functions, equivalent of push() and pushId in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I am using Firebase cloud functions to process my stripe payments. I have some of it set up correctly. When a user authenticates it automatically creates a stripe user. That works great.

Inside of the sample provided by Firebase under 'Adding a payment source' it shows

```
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite((event) =>
```

which should take a payment token provided by stripe and write to the realtime database and update stripe with that token for a user.

However it is very unclear what 'pushID' stands for. I have created numerous attempts such as this one

```
let payment: NSMutableDictionary = ["sources":"stripeCustomerID" ]
self.root.child("stripe_customers").child("FIREBASE USER ID").updateChildValues(payment as! [AnyHashable : Any])
```

but that does not seem to trigger anything in stripe.

Does anyone have an idea of how to structure this call or what the push id is?

The comments in the firebase sample say

> Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe payment
>   source token to Realtime database

Answer (score 2):

In Firebase `pushId` means your database any key name. you can set unique key using `childByAutoId()`

Set path your child, you want to be set auto push id like.

```
let sourcesRef = root.child("stripe_customers").child("FIREBASE USER ID").child("sources")

sourcesRef.child(sourcesRef.childByAutoId().key).child("token").setValue("tokenValue")
```

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39328629/6822622)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What about this call?  // Charge the Stripe customer whenever an amount is written to the Realtime database
         exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}') what would be id? Sorry this is so ambiguous to me.

Comment: this is your live database filed key name. you can set a unique key, you can set childByAutoId key as id in your database.

Comment: you have set a id key in your database, function auto get this id value and execute a func.

Comment: ah yes same as the other which is autoID. I guess whoever wrote the sample just did not stay consistent. Not very clear what to pass back to Stripe, but the errors are giving some indications such as amount missing etc.

Comment: for anyone following just add the "amount": YOURAMOUNTHERE

Comment: @mKane I too am using Firebase Realtime Database and the examples of the Firebase Functions provided are for Cloud Firestore, are you able to please share your final code of the functions provided but for Realtime Database use? I would really appreciate it. I'm learning Swift and not ready to learn JavaScript yet :)

Comment: Do you mean all of my functions for this to work? @Roggie

Comment: hey @mKane if you wouldn't mind sharing the basic functions as per the Stripe examples, and where do you configure your Stripe key for it to work?

Comment: @Roggie I am actually going to make a youtube video explaining step by step how to do this. You can subscribe if you'd like to get an alert when it's live https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClPBd3Y-iuHtWCbSnnMcfcA?view_as=subscriber

Comment: That’s awesome...I will definitely subscribe. Approximately when will it be published?